# Pytest - mocking class instance passed as an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest

Let's say I have a simplified class `Object`:

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def get_data():
        return data.copy()
```

And freestanding function `foo`:

```
def foo(obj: Object):
    copied_data = obj.get_data()
    ...
```

I want to test `foo` and use a fixture with mocked `Object` instance to pass as the argument to `foo`. I want the mocked object to return some predefined data so I need to mock its method as well.

How should I do this in a "proper" way with pytest? I'm not sure how to combine mocks and fixtures.

Comment: There's nothing to mock. `foo` already takes any object you can provide, so just create one that contains the data you need for your test, then pass that to `foo` when you call it.

Comment: @chepner I only need that data but at the same time I need to pass the whole object. Wouldn't that be beneficial to skip the whole creation of the object? In reality the class and constructor are more complicated than here obviously

Comment: If it's more expensive to create an instance of `Object` than it is to create a mock, you're probably doing too much work in `Object.__init__`.

Comment: But maybe you are just talking about passing an instance of `Mock` as the argument to `foo`, rather than an actual instance of `Object`. There's nothing really special to do there, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) and the sample [patching](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) documentations:

> As well as a decorator `patch()` can be used as a context manager in a `with` statement:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> >>> class Class:
> ...     def method(self):
> ...         pass
> ...
> >>> with patch('__main__.Class') as MockClass:
> ...     instance = MockClass.return_value
> ...     instance.method.return_value = 'foo'
> ...     assert Class() is instance
> ...     assert Class().method() == 'foo'
> ...
> ```

We can use [patch()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) inside a fixture and then [yield](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html?highlight=yield#yield-fixtures-recommended) the mocked instance.

**src.py**

```
class Object:
    def __init__(self, data):
        print("Real object initialized")
        self.data = data

    def get_data(self):
        print("Real object get_data")
        return self.data.copy()


def foo(obj: Object):
    print("Object instance:", obj)
    copied_data = obj.get_data()
    return copied_data
```

**test_src.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest

from src import foo, Object


@pytest.fixture
def object_instance():
    with patch('src.Object') as MockClass:
        instance = MockClass.return_value
        instance.get_data.return_value = 'bar'
        yield instance


def test_real_impl():
    object_instance = Object([1, 2])
    assert foo(object_instance) == [1, 2]


def test_mock_impl(object_instance):
    assert foo(object_instance) == 'bar'
```

**Output:**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
================================================================================================= PASSES ==================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ test_real_impl ______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Real object initialized
Object instance: <src.Object object at 0x7fb59ef83820>
Real object get_data
_____________________________________________________________________________________________ test_mock_impl ______________________________________________________________________________________________
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Object instance: <MagicMock name='Object()' id='140418032072736'>
2 passed in 0.06s
```

- As you can see, we are able to create a mocked `Object` and define the return value of its methods.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution and found a dumb bug in my code. Apparently one doesn't have to import unittest and use yield. Passing `mocker` from pytest to the fixture and calling `instance = mocker.patch('__main__.Class')` works fine